# Execute ssh via plink on Windows Host with sudo commands

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, asterisk

I've Windows and I need access to Asterik (Linux server), via SSH, to execute one command. Now I open Putty, enter IP Server, Port, user and password SSH, execute the sudo command, enter password again and I see the result. I want to automate this.  So, I created one script via PLINK:

`plink -ssh -no-antispoof USER@SERVER -pw PASSWORD -t "echo -e PASSWORD | sudo -S asterisk -rx 'sip show peers';`

The command to execute is: sudo asterisk -rx "sip show peers".
The result was:

`[sudo] password for user: sudo: asterisk: command not found`

So, I changed PASSWORD for PASSWORD\n for the next script:

`plink -ssh -no-antispoof USER@SERVER -pw PASSWORD -t "echo -e PASSWORD\n | sudo -S asterisk -rx sip show peers;"`

`[sudo] password for user: Sorry, try again.`

`[sudo] password for user:`

`sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt`

So, I changed for:

`plink -ssh -batch USER@SERVER -pw PASSWORD -m comando.txt`

and comando.txt has:

`echo -e "PASSWORD" | sudo -S asterisk -rx "sip show peers"`

And the result was:

`[sudo] password for user: sudo: asterisk: command not found`

I need to create the script/bat for automate the command, so, in one click I will see the result vía CMD. The problem is the interactive command (sudo asterisk) that require password. **I can't modify the sudoers file due to company policy.**
How can I execute the command with PLINK or other software or solution?

Comment: (1) Is the command “Asterik” or “asterisk”?  If you misspell a command, you are likely to get a “command not found” error.  (2) Where is the command?  (E.g., is it in `/usr/bin`?)  If it’s in some non-default directory, try including the directory in the command.  (3) You indicate that you are constrained by a company security policy.  Are you sure that your company security policy allows storing passwords in plaintext in files? (4) Do you want to run as root or as the “asterisk” user? … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe should be

```
su asterisk -c "/usr/sbin/asterisk -rx 'sip show peers' "
```

See man sudo/man su

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem right here:

```
    asterisk: command not found
```

1. For any kind of automation: try logging into the server manually first, making sure the command you're trying to run will actually run.
2. Once you can run it manually, copy paste the (modified) command and then try it from plink.

To me it looks like it's saying either asterisk is not installed,
or you need to point to asterisk's specific path (like maybe /usr/bin/asterisk or  /opt/bin/asterisk or similar in order to call that executable. (Or as comments above said, maybe it's spelled wrong?)